# Prove that the Ramsey number $R(4,4;3) = 13$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Prove that the Ramsey number $R(4,4;3) = 13$. 
I don't know how to deal with the Ramsey number $R(p_1,p_2,...,p_k;r)$ where r is larger than 2.  
Is there any useful inequality or construction of graph?

Comment: Actually, this is my assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a very hard problem, but I can give you a reference to the paper in which it was solved.

That result appears in Brendan D. McKay & Stanisław P. Radziszowski, *The First Classical Ramsey Number for Hypergraphs Is Computed*, which appeared in $1991$; a PDF can be freely downloaded from [here](http://scholarworks.rit.edu/other/58/). According to the paper’s introduction, Isbell had presented an example in $1969$ to show that $R(4,4;3)\ge 13$; the reference is given. McKay and Radziszowski used a variety of theoretical arguments to narrow the search space and then used a computer to show that $R(4,4;3)\le 13$, thereby establishing the result.

Comment: Thank you, but it's a little hard for me to understand the context. How do Turan set systems work? Or is there any looser bound of $R(4,4;3)$ that is easy to understand?

Comment: @OngDua-Iunn: To be honest, I just found the reference but didn’t look in detail at the analysis; this isn’t my field at all. Giraud’s $1969$ bound of $15$ seems to have involved Turán systems as well, though I couldn’t find a copy of the paper to make certain, and I’m afraid that I don’t know anything about earlier work on hypergraph Ramsey numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that I am probably in the same Graph Theory class with you. After some surveying, I found that this survey, [Small Ramsey Number](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1/pdf), which was published in 2014, stated that the computer-aided proof back in 1991 was the newest.

(Not enough reputation to comment, sorry for not much help provided)

Comment: Thank you. This is a good reference for me!